# Failed to hibernate on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, swap, hibernate

In my previous Kubuntu system I was able to hibernate, but with 22.04 I am unable.
My output for grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=4ff9741-2dc2-4f32-96e3-9b574a7f2739 resume_offset=34818 quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then my output for fstab, specifically the section for swap:

```
swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=14ff9741-2dc2-4f32-96e3-9b574a7f2739 none swap    sw  0       0
```

the output of /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate to be run via cron]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
```

Now when I do df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           785M  2.3M  783M   1% /run
/dev/sda2        24G   14G  8.5G  62% /
tmpfs           3.9G  3.6M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda3       211G  140G   61G  70% /home
/dev/sda1       140M   22M  118M  16% /boot/efi
tmpfs           785M   13M  773M   2% /run/user/1000
```

Swap is supposed to be visible under sda4 with 17gb after I gparted it to increase its size.
Lastly, if I do `systemctl hibernate`
I have this error "Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation"

I really like the option to hibernate as it really save tons of battery and extend the durability of the battery. I also live in a country where shortage of electricity are common.

**EDIT**
Output of swap -s

```
Filename                Type        Size        Used    Priority
/dev/sda4                               partition   17746940    0   -2
```

Comment: Please add output of `swapon -s` command.

Comment: And can you see that you have different UUID in grub and fstab? And what is `res>` there?

Comment: Ah, that might be the cause... I will try it in 15 mints. I have inserted the swap -s output.

Comment: I fixed the UUID of the swap however, when I systemctl hibernate, Ubuntu does not restore the previous session rather it kicks a brand new one. In the meantime I also removed the res> which was resume_offset=34818 but with no luck still.

Comment: maybe stupid question after altering /etc/default/grub did you run `sudo update-grub` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Indeed I found the solution thanks to you all. I will provide the full answer today after work. The issue was the UUID wrong name across the difference places.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution thanks to Pilot6 - I leave this solution ticked with Community Wiki so that he can get recognition.
Indeed Fstab and Grub had different UUID leading to an identity crisis.

1. I found the correct name of the swap via the command `cat /etc/fstab`
2. then edited the `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=14ff9741-2dc2-4f32-96e3-9b574a7f2739 quiet splash"` and updated `sudo update-grub`.
3. I edited: `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` with `RESUME=UUID=14ff9741-2dc2-4f32-96e3-9b574a7f2739` and updated it `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Finally I modified the laptop behavior here `sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf`:
by uncommenting `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate` &
`HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=hibernate`